# Need to show the thankyou message instead of ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was trying to do the form submit response, like on submit the form fields should be hidden and to show the thank you message without refreshing the page, but when i click submit the page is getting refreshed and showing the ajax response {"result":"success","data":"{\"message\":[\"sample message\"]}"

tried using Send Email from a Static HTML Form using Google Apps Mail!

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';


  function getFormData(form) {
    var elements = form.elements;


    var fields = Object.keys(elements).filter().map(function(k) {
      if (elements[k].name !== undefined) {
        return elements[k].name;
        // special case for Edge's html collection
      } else if (elements[k].length > 0) {
        return elements[k].item(0).name;
      }
    }).filter(function(item, pos, self) {
      return self.indexOf(item) == pos && item;
    });

    var formData = {};
    fields.forEach(function(name) {
      var element = elements[name];

      // singular form elements just have one value
      formData[name] = element.value;

      // when our element has multiple items, get their values
      if (element.length) {
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
          var item = element.item(i);
          if (item.checked || item.selected) {
            data.push(item.value);
          }
        }
        formData[name] = data.join(', ');
      }
    });

    // add form-specific values into the data
    formData.formDataNameOrder = JSON.stringify(fields);
    formData.formGoogleSheetName = form.dataset.sheet || "responses"; // default sheet name
    //formData.formGoogleSend = form.dataset.email || ""; // no email by default
    formData.formPage = form.dataset.page || "";

  }

  function handleFormSubmit(event) {
    if (this.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      this.classList.add('was-validated');
    } else if (this.checkValidity() === true) {
      var form = event.target;
      var formData = getFormData(form);
      var data = formData.data;

      var url = form.action;
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', url);
      // xhr.withCredentials = true;
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        form.reset();
        var formElements = form.querySelector(".form-elements")
        if (formElements) {
          formElements.style.display = "none"; // hide form
        }
        var thankYouMessage = form.querySelector(".thankyou_message");
        if (thankYouMessage) {
          thankYouMessage.style.display = "block";
        }
        return;
      };
      // url encode form data for sending as post data
      var encoded = Object.keys(data).map(function(k) {
        return encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[k]);
      }).join('&');
      xhr.send(encoded);
    }
  }

  function loaded() {
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit, false);
    });
  }
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loaded, false);

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="gform  needs-validation" method="POST" data-page="form validation test" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxXw4fshxotq4vkQ3LUjvBaHhjS2RjFvDvKs5FW4w/exec" novalidate>
  <div class="form-elements col-md-6 m-5">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
        <textarea id="visitorMessage" class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        <div class="invalid-tooltip"> Please enter the message </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mx-0" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="thankyou_message" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Thanks for contacting us! We will get back to you soon!</h2>
  </div>
</form>
```

I expect to show the thankyou message without refreshing the page but the actual result is the page getting refreshed and showing the Ajax response

Comment: Have you tried to use a tag other than a button to trigger the click?

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I see none.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with the code you posted.

Comment: I have update the code working example here [codepen](https://codepen.io/thamizh247/pen/VoeVQv) the result is showing _script.googleusercontent.com refused to connect._ page. my exceptation it should show the thankyou message and not to show the script.... refused page

Comment: @Toxide82, yes i tried with tag, getting the same result

Comment: @j08691 it was added mistakenly, i have update code in the codepen link above

Comment: @MarkBaijens, will you please check the codepen link shared above

Answer (score 0):

move `event.preventDefault();` out of the if statement so the default submit action of the form is never triggered. You don't want to do an submit when you do an ajax request since the submit action will navigate to the form action url.

```js
$('.needs-validation').on('submit', handleFormSubmit);

function handleFormSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (this.checkValidity() === true) {
    //Do this in the ajax succes event handler
    $('.thankyou_message').show();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="gform  needs-validation" method="POST" data-page="form validation test" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxXw4fshxotq4vkQ3LUjvBaHhjS2RjFvDvKs5FW4w/exec" novalidate>
  <div class="form-elements col-md-6 m-5">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
        <textarea id="visitorMessage" class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        <div class="invalid-tooltip"> Please enter the message </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mx-0" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="thankyou_message" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Thanks for contacting us! We will get back to you soon!</h2>
  </div>
</form>
```